# Как сериализовать словарь Dictionary<string, string[]>а потом десериализовать

Tags: c#, словари, сериализация, десериализация

Я хочу сохранить данные словаря в  бинарный файл (`.dat`). И при необходимости по ключу доставать оттуда значения.

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dictName = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
        {
            ["Ключ"] = new[] { "значение 1", "значение 2" }
        };
```

Я пытался многими способами, но то поток закрывается, то он не может найти ключ. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нужно больше кода, как вы проводите сериализацию и уточните версию .net

Comment: @Blackmeser версия 4.7.2. А вот как провести сериализацию в данном случае я не знаю и хочу узнать

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.2.php

Comment: Только имейте в виду, что Framework 4.7.2 и `BinaryFormatter` (из ссылки) устарели и на сегодняшний день уже не используются для разработки нового ПО. И зачем вам полностью текстовые данные хранить именно в бинарном файле? Сериализуйте в текстовый формат, например JSON или XML.

Comment: @aepot да я сам не знаю, разрабатываю игру, и по тз сказано было что я должен хранить журнал заданий в бинарном файле, ну или файле у которого доступ защищённым от других людей

Comment: @VALERYSEMENKIN 4.7.2 - это по ТЗ? или есть шанс к примеру на .NET 5 это все сделать?

Comment: @aepot можно и на .NET 5, вполне.

Comment: @aepot главное чтоб в юнити работало

Comment: Unity пока .NET Standard 2.0 вроде, то есть несовместимо с новыми дотнетами. Ну ок 4.7.2, так 4.7.2.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132043/discussion-between-valery-semenkin-and-aepot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покажу пример, как записать и прочитать в двоичном виде показанный словарь с помощью `BinaryWriter` и `BinaryReader`.

Запись

```cs
private static void WriteDictionary(BinaryWriter writer, Dictionary<string, string[]> data)
{
    writer.Write(data.Count);
    foreach (var pair in data)
    {
        writer.Write(pair.Key);
        WriteArray(writer, pair.Value);
    }
}

private static void WriteArray(BinaryWriter writer, string[] array)
{
    writer.Write(array.Length);
    foreach (string item in array)
    {
        writer.Write(item);
    }
}
```

Чтение

```cs
private static Dictionary<string, string[]> ReadDictionary(BinaryReader reader)
{
    int count = reader.ReadInt32();
    Dictionary<string, string[]> data = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        string key = reader.ReadString();
        data[key] = ReadArray(reader);
    }
    return data;
}

private static string[] ReadArray(BinaryReader reader)
{
    string[] array = new string[reader.ReadInt32()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = reader.ReadString();
    }
    return array;
}
```

Проверяем

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, string[]> dictName = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
    {
        ["Ключ"] = new[] { "значение 1", "значение 2" }
    };

    Console.WriteLine("До сериализации:");
    PrintDictionary(dictName);

    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Create("data.dat")))
    {
        WriteDictionary(writer, dictName);
    }

    Dictionary<string, string[]> newDict;
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("data.dat")))
    {
        newDict = ReadDictionary(reader);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("После десереализации:");
    PrintDictionary(newDict);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void PrintDictionary(Dictionary<string, string[]> data) 
{
    foreach (var pair in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{pair.Key}]: {string.Join(",", pair.Value)}");
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
До сериализации:
[Ключ]: значение 1,значение 2
После десереализации:
[Ключ]: значение 1,значение 2
```

Содержимое файла

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Есть еще популярный для старых приложений `BinaryFormatter`, но он является небезопасным и устаревшим. Например, я могу подсунуть в файл любые данные и `BinaryFormatter` прекрасно считает их к вам в память, тем самым можно взломать или сломать приложение. Плюс форматтера в том, что и запись и чтение он выполняет автоматически в одну строчку.

Comment: да, прекрасно работает. Надо будет изучить. Надеюсь в юнити он покажет себя хорошо.

Comment: Благодарен вам всеми фибрами души, очень даже хочу пожать руку за помощь в этому и много раз сказать спасибо.  Невероятно вам благодарен:)

Comment: Вот только одно бы хотелось узнать, как удалить запись. Например у меня там 3 ключа с его значениями. И я хочу их удалить 2 ключ с его значениями при этом  1 и 3 чтоб остались.

Comment: @VALERYSEMENKIN процесс десериализации и сереализации - это просто преобразование данных файла в объект и обратно. Вы не можете просто так взять и отредактировать в режиме реального времени содержимое файла. Вы можете его только полностью прочитать и полностью записать. Вот и получается - читаете словарь, редактируете его как объект и потом пишете обратно в файл. Или у вас проблема с тем как удалить ключ из словаря?

Comment: @VALERYSEMENKIN немного подправил код в ответе, перестарался с закрытием файлов.

Comment: @VALERYSEMENKIN для Unity познакомьтесь с двумя штуками - PlayerPrefs (данные юзера) и JsonUtility (JSON сериализатор, не самый крутой, но зато встроенный).

Comment: В Unity  работает это. Но насчёт удаление. В моё случае словарь в файле это журнал заданий: ключ - название,значения это задание и описание. И когда игрок выполнил квест нужно удалить тот ключ вмести с его значениями.

Comment: @VALERYSEMENKIN `dictName.Remove("Ключ");` я думал, это просто

Comment: просто, но я новичок в программирование и не особо умный человек:)Спасибо, и мне максимально неловко что вы потратили на меня столько времени,за это простите